# Identify crypto from a given wallet address?

Tags: addresses, identity

While relevant to ETH and all of its supported tokens. I am wondering if there is a regex or service available to return a cryptocurrency from a given address.

`0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8` --> ETH

`AdtZpLNgvhyQmiGE9v7XixVDkDWWQh8wY1` --> ARK

`XfmZzu5LGin8sLx6gHtFRxa6y38UoCufqC` --> Dash

Thanks

Comment: What happens if i sent my SALT token to Dash address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the below function `findCoin()` to match addresses to their coin, if there is any match. In general, addresses start with a coin-specific prefix. Also, there is often a fixed length or min/max length for an address. I used those 2 criterias to match bitcoin and ethereum addresses. You can populate the `regex` object with other regular expressions for other coins.

```
var btc = '1BvBMSEYstWetqTFn5Au4m4GFg7xJaNVN2';
var notBtc = '5BvBMSEYstWetqTFn5Au4m4GFg7xJaNVN2';
var eth = '0x0195B59976e33Bb5B8A736a95E589963d866B5A3';
var notEth = '0x0195B59976e33Bb5B8A736a95E589963d866B5A33';

var regex = {
  'BTC': /^(1|3).{25,34}$/,
  'ETH': /^0x.{40}$/,
};

function findCoin(address) {
  var ticker;
  var match = false;
  for(ticker in regex) {
    match = regex[ticker].test(address);
    if(match) break;
  }

  if(match == true) {
    console.log("The address " + address + " is a " + ticker + " address");
  } else {
    console.log("The address " + address + " does not match any coin");
  }
 }

 findCoin(btc);
 findCoin(notBtc);
 findCoin(eth);
 findCoin(notEth);
```